# Performance difference between JQuery event handlers and AngularJS handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, performance

as on element.on vs $scope.$on / ng-keypress / ng-click etc. Do AngularJS event handlers invoke digest cycle each time it is triggered? Are they heavier than JQuery handlers? With a large number of watches in my app, I'm worried if angular directives continuously trigger digest, it will be come very slow (it is right now). Thanks! (NOTE: Angular 1.4)

Comment: can you [identify what creates so many watchers](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/counting-angularjs-watchers-11c5134dc2ef)?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thanks for the article! Unfortunately the app in production has over 15k watchers - I'm in the process of trying to optimize the app. I've reduced it to around 9k with 1 way binding a a few other tricks, so I thought jQuery might be a way to go.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey yes, there's a lot of directives. Due to the nature of the app it's necessary, but I'm also looking into reducing the watchers.

Comment: you would need to make jQuery code part of the `$digest` cycle, and calling it will evaluate other code, making it even slower. [More about it](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey hm I'm assuming you mean I need to call $digest / $apply (good point!)? What about using the event handlers to call functions instead that don't necessarily trigger digest? The handlers were required mostly for things like localization while typing